# Como fazer Request de dados JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, api, request

Preciso coletar alguns dados de um programa que possui API:

[PipeDrive API Reference](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#/)

Se entendi bem, para cada tarefa, sera gerado uma URL para fazer o `Requeste` desdes dados, exemplo:

```
https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?stage_id=45&status=all_not_deleted&start=0&api_token=8***76c******9740**78223a2c
```

Mas como faço para retornar esses dados em minha aplicação?
O metodo é `GET`.

Comment: Você quer saber o quê, especificamente? Como fazer uma requisição para esta API usando C#?

Comment: @LINQ exatamente isso.. obrigado

Comment: Thomas, ainda fica um pouco ampla. Você quer fazer com tudo "na mão"? Usar alguma biblioteca de terceiros?

Comment: @LINQ, então, hoje estou utilizando `Entity Framework`, `Jquery` mas não sei qual seria a melhor abordagem.. Vi o pessoal utilizando `Ajax` para consumir os dados, os dados vindo dessa API, serão atualizados com frequência.. praticamente a cada atualização de pagina, irei precisar ir buscar os dados novamente..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tem algumas abordagens, vou citar à que acho mais apropriada, que é a utilizando o `HttpClient`.

Caso não encontre ele no seu projeto, instale o seguinte pacote.: [`System.Net.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/)

```
public class MinhaController : Controller
{
    // o HttpClient deve ter uma instancia estatica, para evitar ficar abrindo muitas portas.
    private static HttpClient httpClient;

    static MinhaController()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //Se precisar adicionar alguma autenticação, faça o aqui.
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var stageId = GetStageFromSomewhere();
        var token = GetTokenFromSomewhere();
        var queryString = $"?stage_id={stageId}&status=all_not_deleted&start=0&api_token={token}";
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(queryString);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeuModelo>(json)
            return Json(model);
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Erro ao acessar a API.");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

O AP pediu para enumerar algumas demais abordagens, então vamos lá.:

- `HttpWebRequest` - Bastante complexo, porem permite controlar cada aspecto da requisição.
- `WebClient` - Abstração do `HttpWebRequest`, bastante simples, sem muitos controles.
- `HttpClient` - Disponível no `.NET 4.5`, permite operação `async/await` e combina o melhor do `HttpWebRequest` e `WebClient`.
- `RestSharp` - Similar ao `HttpClient`, porem sem o `async/await` e com melhor compatibilidade.

Então, no seu caso, o `HttpClient` é o mais indicado.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta.. poderia descrever quais as outras abordagens? somente o nome para que eu pesquise? obrigado

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel feito.